# Ipython parallel LAN with SSH - ipengine cannot be found

Tags: ssh, parallel-processing, ipython

I am hoping someone might be able to give some light to this issue, google search came out really nothing, that itself is a tell tell sign of I am doing something completely wrong. Anyway this is my setup. Fairly standard trying to run an ipcluster inside a LAN with two other ubuntu 14.04 server machines.

modified the `ipcluster_config.py` to

```
     c.IPClusterEngines.engine_launcher_class = 'SSH'
     c.SSHEngineSetLauncher.engines = { 'hp4@192.168.1.214'  : 2,
                               'hp3@192.168.1.213' : 2 }
```

modified `ipcontroller_config.py`

```
     c.HubFactory.ip =  '*'
```

started the cluster from the client and controller machine with

```
     ipcluster start --profile=ssh --debug
```

now it starts the up the cluster and engines try to connect and then get errored out immediately saying

```
     2015-08-11 17:44:54.757 [IPClusterStart] bash: ipengine: command not
```

found

I can manually login to those machine and do `ipengine` command it connects without issues, so what am I missing

thanks for the input, more detailed log below

```
2015-08-11 17:44:50.494 [IPClusterStart] Config changed:
2015-08-11 17:44:50.494 [IPClusterStart] {'Application': {'log_level': 10}, 'BaseIPythonApplication': {'profile': u'ssh'}}
2015-08-11 17:44:50.494 [IPClusterStart] IPYTHONDIR set to: /home/d752/.ipython
2015-08-11 17:44:50.500 [IPClusterStart] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/d752/.ipython/profile_ssh'
2015-08-11 17:44:50.501 [IPClusterStart] Searching path [u'/home/d752/JP/ipythonwork', u'/home/d752/.ipython/profile_ssh', '/usr/local/etc/ipython', '/etc/ipython'] for config files
2015-08-11 17:44:50.501 [IPClusterStart] Attempting to load config file: ipython_config.py
2015-08-11 17:44:50.502 [IPClusterStart] Loaded config file: /home/d752/.ipython/profile_ssh/ipython_config.py
2015-08-11 17:44:50.502 [IPClusterStart] Attempting to load config file: ipcluster_config.py
2015-08-11 17:44:50.503 [IPClusterStart] Loaded config file: /home/d752/.ipython/profile_ssh/ipcontroller_config.py
2015-08-11 17:44:50.504 [IPClusterStart] Config changed:
2015-08-11 17:44:50.504 [IPClusterStart] {'Application': {'log_level': 10}, 'BaseIPythonApplication': {'profile': u'ssh'}, 'HubFactory': {'ip': '*'}}
2015-08-11 17:44:50.505 [IPClusterStart] Attempting to load config file: ipcluster_config.py
2015-08-11 17:44:50.505 [IPClusterStart] Loaded config file: /home/d752/.ipython/profile_ssh/ipengine_config.py
2015-08-11 17:44:50.506 [IPClusterStart] Attempting to load config file: ipcluster_config.py
2015-08-11 17:44:50.507 [IPClusterStart] Loaded config file: /home/d752/.ipython/profile_ssh/ipcluster_config.py
2015-08-11 17:44:50.508 [IPClusterStart] Config changed:
2015-08-11 17:44:50.508 [IPClusterStart] {'Application': {'log_level': 10}, 'BaseIPythonApplication': {'profile': u'ssh'}, 'HubFactory': {'ip': '*'}, 'IPClusterEngines': {'engine_launcher_class': 'SSH'}, 'SSHEngineSetLauncher': {'engines': {'hp4@192.168.1.214': 2, 'hp3@192.168.1.213': 2}}}
2015-08-11 17:44:50.511 [IPClusterStart] Starting ipcluster with [daemon=False]
2015-08-11 17:44:50.512 [IPClusterStart] Creating pid file: /home/d752/.ipython/profile_ssh/pid/ipcluster.pid
2015-08-11 17:44:50.512 [IPClusterStart] Starting Controller with LocalControllerLauncher
2015-08-11 17:44:50.512 [IPClusterStart] Starting LocalControllerLauncher: ['/home/d752/anaconda/bin/python', '-m', 'IPython.parallel.controller', '--profile-dir', u'/home/d752/.ipython/profile_ssh', '--cluster-id', u'', '--log-to-file', '--log-level=20']
2015-08-11 17:44:50.515 [IPClusterStart] Process '/home/d752/anaconda/bin/python' started: 14930
2015-08-11 17:44:50.889 [IPClusterStart] 2015-08-11 17:44:50.888 [IPControllerApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/home/d752/.ipython/profile_ssh'
2015-08-11 17:44:51.174 [IPClusterStart] 2015-08-11 17:44:51.174 [scheduler] Scheduler started [leastload]
2015-08-11 17:44:51.516 [IPClusterStart] Starting 4 Engines with SSH
2015-08-11 17:44:51.518 [IPClusterStart] ensuring remote hp3@192.168.1.213:.ipython/profile_ssh/security/ exists
Connection to 192.168.1.213 closed.
2015-08-11 17:44:51.901 [IPClusterStart] sending /home/d752/.ipython/profile_ssh/security/ipcontroller-client.json to hp3@192.168.1.213:.ipython/profile_ssh/security/ipcontroller-client.json
2015-08-11 17:44:52.273 [IPClusterStart] ensuring remote hp3@192.168.1.213:.ipython/profile_ssh/security/ exists
Connection to 192.168.1.213 closed.
2015-08-11 17:44:52.654 [IPClusterStart] sending /home/d752/.ipython/profile_ssh/security/ipcontroller-engine.json to hp3@192.168.1.213:.ipython/profile_ssh/security/ipcontroller-engine.json
2015-08-11 17:44:53.030 [IPClusterStart] Starting SSHEngineLauncher: ['ssh', '-tt', u'hp3@192.168.1.213', 'ipengine', '--profile-dir', u'.ipython/profile_ssh', '--log-to-file', '--log-level=20']
2015-08-11 17:44:53.034 [IPClusterStart] Process 'ssh' started: 14955
2015-08-11 17:44:53.136 [IPClusterStart] Starting SSHEngineLauncher: ['ssh', '-tt', u'hp3@192.168.1.213', 'ipengine', '--profile-dir', u'.ipython/profile_ssh', '--log-to-file', '--log-level=20']
2015-08-11 17:44:53.139 [IPClusterStart] Process 'ssh' started: 14956
2015-08-11 17:44:53.141 [IPClusterStart] ensuring remote hp4@192.168.1.214:.ipython/profile_ssh/security/ exists
Connection to 192.168.1.214 closed.
2015-08-11 17:44:53.516 [IPClusterStart] sending /home/d752/.ipython/profile_ssh/security/ipcontroller-client.json to hp4@192.168.1.214:.ipython/profile_ssh/security/ipcontroller-client.json
2015-08-11 17:44:53.892 [IPClusterStart] ensuring remote hp4@192.168.1.214:.ipython/profile_ssh/security/ exists
Connection to 192.168.1.214 closed.
2015-08-11 17:44:54.271 [IPClusterStart] sending /home/d752/.ipython/profile_ssh/security/ipcontroller-engine.json to hp4@192.168.1.214:.ipython/profile_ssh/security/ipcontroller-engine.json
2015-08-11 17:44:54.648 [IPClusterStart] Starting SSHEngineLauncher: ['ssh', '-tt', u'hp4@192.168.1.214', 'ipengine', '--profile-dir', u'.ipython/profile_ssh', '--log-to-file', '--log-level=20']
2015-08-11 17:44:54.651 [IPClusterStart] Process 'ssh' started: 14963
2015-08-11 17:44:54.754 [IPClusterStart] Starting SSHEngineLauncher: ['ssh', '-tt', u'hp4@192.168.1.214', 'ipengine', '--profile-dir', u'.ipython/profile_ssh', '--log-to-file', '--log-level=20']
2015-08-11 17:44:54.757 [IPClusterStart] Process 'ssh' started: 14964
2015-08-11 17:44:54.757 [IPClusterStart] Process 'engine set' started: [None, None, None, None]
2015-08-11 17:44:54.757 [IPClusterStart] bash: ipengine: command not found
2015-08-11 17:44:54.758 [IPClusterStart] Connection to 192.168.1.213 closed.
2015-08-11 17:44:54.758 [IPClusterStart] bash: ipengine: command not found
2015-08-11 17:44:54.758 [IPClusterStart] Connection to 192.168.1.213 closed.
2015-08-11 17:44:54.758 [IPClusterStart] Process 'ssh' stopped: {'pid': 14955, 'exit_code': 127}
2015-08-11 17:44:54.758 [IPClusterStart] Process 'ssh' stopped: {'pid': 14956, 'exit_code': 127}
2015-08-11 17:44:55.026 [IPClusterStart] bash: ipengine: command not found
2015-08-11 17:44:55.026 [IPClusterStart] Connection to 192.168.1.214 closed.
2015-08-11 17:44:55.026 [IPClusterStart] Process 'ssh' stopped: {'pid': 14963, 'exit_code': 127}
2015-08-11 17:44:55.130 [IPClusterStart] bash: ipengine: command not found
2015-08-11 17:44:55.130 [IPClusterStart] Connection to 192.168.1.214 closed.
2015-08-11 17:44:55.130 [IPClusterStart] Process 'ssh' stopped: {'pid': 14964, 'exit_code': 127}
2015-08-11 17:44:55.130 [IPClusterStart] Process 'engine set' stopped: {'192.168.1.213/0': {'pid': 14955, 'exit_code': 127}, '192.168.1.213/1': {'pid': 14956, 'exit_code': 127}, '192.168.1.214/1': {'pid': 14964, 'exit_code': 127}, '192.168.1.214/0': {'pid': 14963, 'exit_code': 127}}
2015-08-11 17:44:55.130 [IPClusterStart] ERROR | 
            Engines shutdown early, they probably failed to connect.

            Check the engine log files for output.

            If your controller and engines are not on the same machine, you probably
            have to instruct the controller to listen on an interface other than localhost.

            You can set this by adding "--ip='*'" to your ControllerLauncher.controller_args.

            Be sure to read our security docs before instructing your controller to listen on
            a public interface.

2015-08-11 17:44:55.131 [IPClusterStart] ERROR | IPython cluster: stopping
2015-08-11 17:44:55.163 [IPClusterStart] Process '/home/d752/anaconda/bin/python' stopped: {'pid': 14930, 'exit_code': 0}
2015-08-11 17:44:58.132 [IPClusterStart] Removing pid file: /home/d752/.ipython/profile_ssh/pid/ipcluster.pid
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here is how I've solved it.

In my case, my ipcluster_config.py has the following setting:

```
c.SSHEngineSetLauncher.engines = {
 'host1' : 4,
 'host2' : 8,
 'host3' : 4,
}
```

The ipengine launcher was not being found in each server. I created an alias to ipengine in all machines (controller and clients):

```
sudo ln -s PATH_TO_IPENGINE_BINARY /opt/ipengine
```

which is pointing to the Anaconda ipengine in my case.

Then I changed the following variable in ipcluster_config.py:

```
c.SSHEngineSetLauncher.engine_cmd = ['/opt/ipengine']
```

In case you have different usernames in the different clients, it is very convenient to create a .ssh/config file in the controller machine setting everything up. For example:

```
Host host1
  HostName xx.xxx.x.xxx
  User me

Host host2
  HostName xx.xxx.x.xxx
  User myself

Host host3
  HostName xx.xxx.x.xxx
  User irene
```

Also, make sure you have configures passwordless SSH login in each machine. Now it should work, I hope.